# Use Greensock TweenMax inside Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, gsap, reveal.js

I am trying to use Greensock TweenMax for animation in Reveal.js but it is not working properly. For example:

```
TweenMax.to(logo, 2, {x:"500px"});
```

The second argument is for the duration of the animation, but implemented in Reveal.js it is working like delay. I am trying to use TimelineLite but it is not working at all.

Can someone example how to properly use greensock with reveal.js?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Kindly provide details of how you have tried to solve the problem. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1):

go to http://www.greensock.com/jump-start-js/ to see tips on how you may write your code.

Second, using `TweenMax.to(logo, 2, {x:"500px"});`, with *x* as the element to tween may go to an error. This can be used in AS3, but in javascript, the guys of Greensock recommends the use of `top, left, etc.`, like in `TweenLite.to(logo, 1, {left:"632px"});`

Also, check my last question, i´m sure you will find it useful: [How to trigger a GSAP function when a slide comes active with Reveal.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936987/how-to-trigger-a-gsap-function-when-a-slide-comes-active-with-reveal-js)

Hope this can help you.

Comment: That is not correct mate, animating the x value in HTML is much better than the actual left element in terms of performance. As { x: "500px" } is the same as transform: translateX(500px); This is actually recommended by Greensock instead of moving absolute positions.