# How to trigger a GSAP function when a slide comes active with Reveal.js?

Tags: javascript, reveal.js, gsap

I want to add some simple animation to a presentation. I use GSAP (TweenMax) for this work. I have no problem with the animation setup, but these animations triggers as soon the presentation starts.

How can I control this, so that only when the slide with animations is active the scripts execute?

All your help is welcome.
Regards!

EDIT:

Well, looks like reading the docs of the libraries answers at least 90% of this kind of questions.
For the lazies (like me :) ) here´s what I found:

To check when the slide change, we use this:

```
 Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    // event.previousSlide, event.currentSlide, event.indexh, event.indexv
} );
```

And in my animeScript.js, I just link the event, just like:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slidechanged', function( event ) {
    myTween();
} );
```

If we want to target a specific slide, we use *`data-state`* argument in the *`<section></section>`* tags like:

```
<section data-state="slide2">
  <img id="logo2" src="images/logo.png">
  <h2>No Theme</h2>
  <p>There's no theme included, so it will fall back on browser defaults.</p>
</section>
```

And link the state in the animeScript.js like:

```
Reveal.addEventListener( 'slide2', function() {
  myTween();
  TweenMax.to(logo3, 1,{opacity:1, delay:1.5});
}, false );
```

Regards!